# Device works powered from benchtop PSU but not from battery

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, batteries

I have a very simple Power ON/OFF switch based on MAX1614. My device works perfectly when powered from a benchtop PSU. However, when powering from LiIon battery pack, I get the "run-through", and my battery voltage appears on the output port immediately after connection.

My /ON is connected through a push-button to the ground. /OFF is floating (both /ON and /OFF have weak pull-ups in the MAX1614). I don't need LBI/LBO functionality, so the pins are floating.

Is there something extra I need to consider when powering from the battery compared to the benchtop PSU?

[image]

Comment: Strange. Can you show oscillograms of both cases?

Comment: who is driving ON & OFF? I went through the datasheet and there is a latch in MAX1614 whose output controls the NMOS gate. So, we need to see how you ensure the latch is in the correct state upon connecting the battery.

Comment: In a typical application, they seem to connect a resistor divider from BATT to LBI to ground and connect LBO to OFF. This ensures that the latch is reset and hence NMOS is OFF until ON is driven low.

Comment: I will add oscillograms as soon as I can hook it up on the scope. Re On/Off: On is push button to the ground, OFF is floating (there's a weak pull-up in MAX1614). Re LBI/LBO - I don't need this functionality (ie. I don't need the device to turn off at LBI trip level)

Comment: May be add a 10pF cap on OFF to ground & may be also say 100M ohm resistor in parallel and see if that helps. My theory of latch starting in a random state is questionable because there is a POR  that resets the latch.